# getting error 'TypeError: newData is not iterable'

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to add the objects into the localstorage by the use of state but not able to get the desired results as i want to save the username,password,firstname,last name into the localstorage and also display these elements of object into the HomePage and getting error 'TypeError: newData is not iterable'....Any help will be much appreciated.

```
App.js

import LoginForm from "./Component/LoginForm/LoginForm";
import HomePage from "./Component/HomePage/HomePage";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";


const user = [];
function App() {
  const [isLoggedIn, setIsLoggedIn] = useState(false);
  const [userData,setUserData] = useState(user);
  console.log('userData: ',userData);
  localStorage.setItem('CompleteData',JSON.stringify(userData));
  const getObj = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('CompleteData'));
  console.log('getObj: ',getObj);
  useEffect(() => {
    const isUserLoggedIn = localStorage.getItem("isLoggedInn");
    if (isUserLoggedIn === "1") {
      setIsLoggedIn(true);
    }
  }, []);
  const loginHandler = (username,first,last,pass) => {
    localStorage.setItem("isLoggedInn", "1");
    setIsLoggedIn(true);
    localStorage.setItem('currentUsername',username);
    localStorage.setItem('currentFirstname',first);
    localStorage.setItem('currentLastname',last);
    localStorage.setItem('currentPassword',pass);
  };
  const logoutHandler = () => {
    localStorage.removeItem("isLoggedInn");
    setIsLoggedIn(false);
  };
  const onSaveDataHandler = (newData) => {
      setUserData((prevData)=>{
        return [prevData,...newData];
      });
    };  
  const dataFormHandler = (username, first,last,pass) => {
    return [
      localStorage.getItem('currentUsername'),
      localStorage.getItem('currentFirstname'),
      localStorage.getItem('currentLastname'),
      localStorage.getItem('currentPassword')
    ];
  }
  return (
    <>
    <div>
      {!isLoggedIn && (
        <LoginForm
          onLogin={loginHandler}
          onSaveData={onSaveDataHandler}
          usersD={getObj}
        />
      )}
      {isLoggedIn && (
        <HomePage onLogout={logoutHandler} user={dataFormHandler()} />
      )}
    </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;

import styles from "./LoginForm.module.css";
import { useState } from "react";
import SignUp from "../SignUp/SignUp";
const LoginForm = (props) => {
  const [enteredUsername, setEnteredUsername] = useState("");
  const [enteredPassword, setEnteredPassword] = useState("");
  const [isTrue, setTrue] = useState(true);
  const [isClicked, setIsClicked] = useState(false);

  const onChangeHandlerUsername = (event) => {
    setEnteredUsername(event.target.value);
    if (event.target.value === enteredUsername) {
      setTrue(true);
    }
  };
  const onChangeHandlerPassword = (event) => {
    setEnteredPassword(event.target.value);
    if (event.target.value === enteredPassword) {
      setTrue(true);
    }
  };
  const onSubmitHandler = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    props.usersD.forEach((element,i)=>{
      if (
        enteredUsername === element[i].username &&
        enteredPassword === element[i].password
      ){
      props.onLogin(element[i].username,element[i].firstname,element[i].lastname,element[i].password);
    }
      else {
        setTrue(false);
      };
    })
  };
  const onClickHandler = () => {
    setIsClicked(true);
  };
  const sendDataToChild = (entereduserData) =>{
    const userData = {
      id: Math.random().toString(),
      ...entereduserData
    };
    props.onSaveData(userData);
  }
  return (
    <>
      {isClicked &&
      enteredUsername !== Object.keys(props.usersD).username &&
      enteredPassword !== Object.keys(props.usersD).password ? (
        <SignUp dataTransfer={sendDataToChild} clk={setIsClicked}/>
      ) : (
        <form onSubmit={onSubmitHandler}>
          <h1 className={styles.blink_me}>W E L C O M E</h1>
          <div className={`${styles.box} ${!isTrue && styles.wrong}`}>
            <h1>Login</h1>
            <input
              type="text"
              value={enteredUsername}
              placeholder="Enter Username"
              className={styles.email}
              onChange={onChangeHandlerUsername}
            ></input>
            <input
              type="password"
              value={enteredPassword}
              placeholder="Enter Password"
              className={styles.email}
              onChange={onChangeHandlerPassword}
            ></input>
            <div>
              <button className={styles.btn}>Sign In</button>
            </div>
            <div>
              <button
                onClick={onClickHandler}
                type="button"
                className={styles.btn2}
              >
                Sign Up
              </button>
            </div>
            <div>
              <a href="#top">Forget Password</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
      )}
    </>
  );
};
export default LoginForm;
```

HomePage.js

```
import styler from './HomePage.module.css';

const HomePage = (props) =>{
    const name = props.user[0];
    const first = props.user[1];
    const last = props.user[2];
    const pass = props.user[3];
    return(
        <>
        <div className={styler.body}>
        <h2>Login Successfull !</h2>
        {/* {props.user.map(users=><p username={users[0]} password={users[1]}/>)} */}
        <p>Name: {name}</p>
        <p>FirstName: {first}</p>
        <p>LastName: {last}</p>
        <p>Password: {pass}</p>
        <button type='submit' onClick={props.onLogout} className={styler.button}>Logout</button>
        </div>
        </>
    );
}
export default HomePage;
```

Comment: Shouldn't you be passing newData as a parameter in 
<LoginForm
          onLogin={loginHandler}
          onSaveData={onSaveDataHandler}
          usersD={getObj}
        />

Comment: what is newData supposed to be?

Comment: What does `<SignUp dataTransfer={sendDataToChild} clk={setIsClicked}/>` do with the `sendDataToChild` callback, or what is it passing to it?

Comment: sendDataToChild is used to pass the data from child(LoginForm) to parent(App)  and newData is the object containing the data that we will get from SignUp page...I want to get this data to App and than created a state  through which i will get the new data from signup page and append it to the prevState and than return it to userData which initially contain the empty user array and than storing each new state in the local storage.